# Show that two metrics are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the two metrics are equivalent.

Suppose we have a metric space $X \times Y$. Two metrics are defined as:

$d_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y')) := \max\{d_X(x, x'), d_Y(y, y')\}$

$d'_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y')) := d_X(x, x')+d_Y(y, y')$

Here is my attempt at proof:

Define $\tau$ to be the collection of open sets with respect to $d_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y'))$ . Also define $\tau*$ to be the collection of open sets with respect to $d'_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y'))$.

First, assume an open set $U \in \tau$. We want to show that $U \in \tau*$.

Since $U \in \tau$, $\forall (x, y) \in U$, $\exists p > 0$ such that $B_{p}^{d} (x, y) \subset U$.

Then $\forall (x, y) \in U$, $B_{p/2}^{d} (x, y) \subset U.$
Since $d_X(x,x') + d_Y(y, y') \leqslant 2 \cdot \max\{d_X(x, x'), d_Y(y, y')\}$,

If we set $r := 2 \cdot \max\{d_X(x, x'), d_Y(y, y')\}$ then
$B_{r}^{d'}(x,y) \subset B_{p/2}^{d} \subset U$.

As you can see, this reasoning is confusing, in fact I got confused writing this. I can kind of see the direction I should head to but this is not it. Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks.

If I get this part correct I think I can handle the converse.

Comment: Btw, remember that to prove two metrics are equivalent you can prove that there exist two constants $C_1,C_2>0$ such that $$C_1 d(x,y) \leq d'(x,y) \leq C_2 d(x,y)$$.

Answer (score 0):

First prove that $d_{X\times Y}\leq d'_{X\times Y}\leq 2d_{X\times Y}$.

Then you can easily deduce that for any point $p$ in $X\times Y$ and any $r>0$, $B_r^{d}\subseteq (p)B_{2r}^{d'}(p)\subseteq B_{2r}^d(p)$. This proves the equivalence of the two metrics.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y$ are non negative, we have
$x+y \le 2 \max(x,y)$ and $\max(x,y) \le x+y$.

Hence 
$d'_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y')) \le 2 d_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y'))$ and
$d_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y')) \le d'_{X \times Y}((x, y), (x', y'))$.

Answer (score 0):

Why make this so complicated when you are almost done:

See that if we allow $(a,b)\in \operatorname{B_d^p(x,y)}$(I have kept your notations intact);

Then $d((a,b),(x,y))<p\implies d_X(a,x)<p;d_Y(b,y)<p\implies d^{'}((a,b),(x,y))<2p$

Then choose $q=p$ then we have $(a,b)\in \operatorname{B_{d^{'}}^q(x,y)}\subseteq \operatorname{B_d^p(x,y)}$

Similarly the converse.